# themoviedb 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, themoviedb-api

Anyone else having this issue with themoviedb api?

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key=XXX&query=mr.%20robot. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://van-der-noord.nl' is therefore not allowed access.

I'm pretty sure this use to work without having te set chrome's cross domain policy.

Any idea?

Comment: looking at how https://github.com/cavestri/themoviedb-javascript-library/blob/master/themoviedb.js does it, it seems that the content-type headers might trigger the cors headers...

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to add a callback parameter:

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key=XXX&query=mr.%20robot&callback=test
```

And then call that however Angular expects JSONP callbacks to be used.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
const requests = {
    fetchTrending : `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/week?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`
}
```

Instead of having the base url in axios.js, let it be in the above format so axios.js doesn't exist. **Note:** When calling axios, make sure you import it globally. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Google Chrome extension
**Allow-Control-Allow-Origin:** Maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

This error caused by CORS

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

- You can use [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/reviews?hl=en) to enable this feature
- [Disable web security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

But this solutions only works for you. If you need work this on every computer you need to setup some kinda proxy file, or you can use JSONP version.

http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#reference

> Unlike previous versions of the API, v3 only supports a single format, JSON. XML and YAML support are being officially dropped. JSONP is also officially supported, just add a callback parameter to your request and the response will be encapsulated in the value you specified.

Since you need to use API key to fetch information, i suggest you to use proxy file to get it for you.